# Как написать свою первую нейронную сеть на C++?

Tags: c++, нейронные-сети

Я перепрочитал многие статьи, знаю, что такое сигмоид и другие функции активации, знаю метод обратного распространения и другие формулы. Я не могу лишь начать. Я читал коды других, но они были просто ужасны и без подробных объяснении. Имеются основные знания по C++, владение STL, многотопочностью и немного QT так же есть. Задачи решал. Пожалуйста, скажите, что мне, человеку, который прочитал лишь статьи на хабре по этой теме, делать.

Comment: Напиши самую простую нейронную сеть. Где все через многомерные массивы (например трехмерный массив под веса) и самые стандартные функции `forward`, `findError` ну типа такого. Потом протести свою нейронку на каком нибудь максимально простом примере. например `xor`. А дальше попробуй использовать ООП. И задачу например распознание цифр. Обучающую выборку можно взять [тут](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). Если хотите можем связаться, могу показать свою минимальную нейронку.

Comment: в большинстве случаев, нейронные сети - это (ну если супер грубо) просто умножение матриц. и все. Другое дело, что их нужно посчитать (называется "обучить"). Тут чуточку больше умножений, но все равно те же умножения.

Answer (score -1):

Да много я годков потратил чтобы сварганить следующий код на Python.4-5.Начиная анализы с numpy.Вы можете конвертировать в С, главное организовать статические массивы-они быстрее, for row in range(n) это всегда for(int row=0;row<n;row++){...}.Итак)

```python
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import random
from serial_deserial import to_file, deserialization
import sys


TRESHOLD_FUNC = 0
TRESHOLD_FUNC_DERIV = 1
SIGMOID = 2
SIGMOID_DERIV = 3
RELU = 4
RELU_DERIV = 5
TAN = 6
TAN_DERIV = 7
INIT_W_MY = 8
INIT_W_RANDOM = 9
LEAKY_RELU = 10
LEAKY_RELU_DERIV = 11
INIT_W_CONST = 12
INIT_W_RANDN = 13
SOFTMAX = 14
SOFTMAX_DERIV = 15
PIECE_WISE_LINEAR = 16
PIECE_WISE_LINEAR_DERIV = 17
TRESHOLD_FUNC_HALF = 18
TRESHOLD_FUNC_HALF_DERIV = 19
MODIF_MSE = 20

NOOP = 0
ACC_GRAD = 1
APPLY_GRAD = 2


class Dense:
    def __init__(self):  # конструктор
        self.in_ = None  # количество входов слоя
        self.out_ = None  # количество выходов слоя
        self.matrix = [0] * 10  # матрица весов
        self.biases = [0] * 10
        self.cost_signals = [0] * 10  # вектор взвешенного состояния нейронов
        self.act_func = RELU
        self.hidden = [0] * 10  # вектор после функции активации
        self.errors = [0] * 10  # вектор ошибок слоя
        self.with_bias = False
        for row in range(10):  # создаем матрицу весов
            # подготовка матрицы весов,внутренняя матрица
            self.inner_m = list([0] * 10)
            self.matrix[row] = self.inner_m


################### Функции обучения ######################


class NetCon:
    def __init__(self, alpha_sigmoid=1, alpha_tan=1, beta_tan=1):
        self.net = [None] * 2  # Двойной перпецетрон
        self.alpha_sigmoid = alpha_sigmoid
        self.alpha_tan = alpha_tan
        self.beta_tan = beta_tan
        for l_ind in range(2):
            self.net[l_ind] = Dense()
        self.sp_d = -1  # алокатор для слоев
        self.nl_count = 0  # количество слоев
        self.ready = False

    def make_hidden(self, layer_ind, inputs: list):
        layer = self.net[layer_ind]
        for row in range(layer.out_):
            tmp_v = 0
            for elem in range(layer.in_):
                tmp_v += layer.matrix[row][elem] * inputs[elem]
            if layer.with_bias:
                tmp_v += layer.biases[row]
            layer.cost_signals[row] = tmp_v
            val = self.operations(layer.act_func, tmp_v)
            layer.hidden[row] = val

    def get_hidden(self, objLay: Dense):
        return objLay.hidden

    def feed_forwarding(self, inputs):
        self.make_hidden(0, inputs)
        j = self.nl_count
        for i in range(1, j):
            inputs = self.get_hidden(self.net[i - 1])
            self.make_hidden(i, inputs)

        last_layer = self.net[j-1]

        return self.get_hidden(last_layer)

    def cr_lay(self,   in_=0, out_=0, act_func=None, with_bias=False, init_w=INIT_W_RANDOM):
        self.sp_d += 1
        layer = self.net[self.sp_d]
        layer.in_ = in_
        layer.out_ = out_
        layer.act_func = act_func

        if with_bias:
            layer.with_bias = True
        else:
            layer.with_bias = False

        for row in range(out_):
            for elem in range(in_):
                layer.matrix[row][elem] = self.operations(
                    init_w, 0)
            layer.biases[row] = self.operations(
                init_w, 0)
        self.nl_count += 1

    # Различные операции по числовому коду

    def operations(self, op, x):
        alpha_leaky_relu = 1.7159
        alpha_sigmoid = 2
        alpha_tan = 1.7159
        beta_tan = 2/3
        if op == RELU:
            if (x <= 0):
                return 0
            else:
                return x
        elif op == RELU_DERIV:
            if (x <= 0):
                return 0
            else:
                return 1
        elif op == TRESHOLD_FUNC:
            if (x > 0):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        elif op == TRESHOLD_FUNC_HALF:
            if x >= 1/2:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        elif op == TRESHOLD_FUNC_HALF_DERIV:
            return 1
        elif op == PIECE_WISE_LINEAR:
            if x >= 1/2:
                return 1
            elif x < 1/2 and x > -1/2:
                return x
            elif x <= -1/2:
                return 0
        elif op == PIECE_WISE_LINEAR_DERIV:
            return 1
        elif op == TRESHOLD_FUNC_DERIV:
            return 1
        elif op == LEAKY_RELU:
            if (x <= 0):
                return alpha_leaky_relu
            else:
                return 1
        elif op == LEAKY_RELU_DERIV:
            if (x <= 0):
                return alpha_leaky_relu
            else:
                return 1
        elif op == SIGMOID:
            y = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-self.alpha_sigmoid * x))
            return y
        elif op == SIGMOID_DERIV:
            return self.alpha_sigmoid * x * (1 - x)
        elif op == INIT_W_MY:
            if self.ready:
                self.ready = False
                return -0.567141530112327
            self.ready = True
            return 0.567141530112327
        elif op == INIT_W_RANDOM:

            return random.random()
        elif op == TAN:
            y = alpha_tan * math.tanh(beta_tan * x)
            return y
        elif op == TAN_DERIV:
            y = alpha_tan * math.tanh(beta_tan * x)
            return beta_tan / alpha_tan * (alpha_tan * alpha_tan - y * y)
        elif op == INIT_W_CONST:
            return 0.567141530112327
        elif op == INIT_W_RANDN:
            return np.random.randn()
        else:
            print("Op or function does not support ", op)

    def calc_out_error(self,  targets):
        layer = self.net[self.nl_count-1]
        out_ = layer.out_
        for row in range(out_):
            layer.errors[row] =\
                (layer.hidden[row] - targets[row]) * self.operations(
                layer.act_func + 1, layer.hidden[row])

    def calc_hid_error(self,  layer_ind):
        layer = self.net[layer_ind]
        layer_next = self.net[layer_ind + 1]
        for elem in range(layer_next.in_):
            summ = 0
            for row in range(layer_next.out_):
                summ += layer_next.matrix[row][elem] * \
                    layer_next.errors[row]
            layer.errors[elem] = summ * self.operations(
                layer.act_func + 1, layer.hidden[elem])

    def upd_matrix(self, layer_ind, errors, inputs, lr):
        layer = self.net[layer_ind]
        for row in range(layer.out_):
            error = errors[row]
            for elem in range(layer.in_):
                layer.matrix[row][elem] -= lr * \
                    error * inputs[elem]
            if layer.with_bias:
                layer.biases[row] -= error * 1

    def calc_diff(self, out_nn, teacher_answ):
        diff = [0] * len(out_nn)
        for row in range(len(teacher_answ)):
            diff[row] = out_nn[row] - teacher_answ[row]
        return diff

    def get_err(self, diff):
        sum = 0
        for row in range(len(diff)):
            sum += diff[row] * diff[row]
        return sum

    def backpropagate(self, y, x, l_r):
        j = self.nl_count
        print('j', j)
        for i in range(j - 1, -1, - 1):
            if i == j - 1:
                self.calc_out_error(y)
            else:
                self.calc_hid_error(i)

        for i in range(j - 1, 0, - 1):
            layer = self.net[i]
            layer_prev = self.net[i - 1]
            self.upd_matrix(i, layer.errors, layer_prev.hidden, l_r)

        self.upd_matrix(0, self.net[0].errors,
                        x, l_r)


#############################################


def plot_gr(_file: str, errors: list, epochs: list) -> None:
    fig: plt.Figure = None
    ax: plt.Axes = None
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(epochs, errors,
            label="learning",
            )
    plt.xlabel('Эпоха обучения')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    ax.legend()
    plt.savefig(_file)
    print("Graphic saved")
    plt.show()


train_inp = ((1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0))  # Логическое И
train_out = ([1], [0], [0], [0])


def main():
    epochs = 1000
    l_r = 0.1

    errors_y = []
    epochs_x = []

    # Создаем обьект параметров сети

    net = NetCon()
    # Создаем слои
    net.cr_lay(2, 3, PIECE_WISE_LINEAR, True, INIT_W_MY)
    net.cr_lay(3, 1, PIECE_WISE_LINEAR, True, INIT_W_MY)

    for ep in range(epochs):  # Кол-во повторений для обучения
        gl_e = 0
        for single_array_ind in range(len(train_inp)):

            inputs = train_inp[single_array_ind]
            output = net.feed_forwarding(inputs)

            e = net.calc_diff(output, train_out[single_array_ind])

            gl_e += net.get_err(e)

            net.backpropagate(train_out[single_array_ind],
                              train_inp[single_array_ind], l_r)

        #gl_e /= 2
        print("error", gl_e)
        print("ep", ep)
        print()

        errors_y.append(gl_e)
        epochs_x.append(ep)

        if gl_e == 0:
            break

    plot_gr('gr.png', errors_y, epochs_x)
    
    # пост оценка - evaluate()
    for single_array_ind in range(len(train_inp)):
        inputs = train_inp[single_array_ind]

        output_2_layer = net.feed_forwarding(inputs)

        equal_flag = 0
        out_net = net.net[1].out_
        for row in range(out_net):
            elem_net = output_2_layer[row]
            elem_train_out = train_out[single_array_ind][row]
            if elem_net > 0.5:
                elem_net = 1
            else:
                elem_net = 0
            print("elem:", elem_net)
            print("elem tr out:", elem_train_out)
            if elem_net == elem_train_out:
                equal_flag = 1
            else:
                equal_flag = 0
                break
        if equal_flag == 1:
            print('-vecs are equal-')
        else:
            print('-vecs are not equal-')

        print("========")

    # to_file(nn_params, nn_params.net, loger, 'wei1.my')


main()

Graphic saved
elem: 1
elem tr out: 1
-vecs are equal-
========
elem: 0
elem tr out: 0
-vecs are equal-
========
elem: 0
elem tr out: 0
-vecs are equal-
========
elem: 0
elem tr out: 0
-vecs are equal-
========
```

[image: кул]